# Adding changes from master branch to local branch

Tags: git, github

I am using Git and I have pulled the changes in my master branch but the changes don't appear to be in my local branch. I read online that we can do

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch-name
git merge master
```

I don't want to push any changes to master or to github for my branch to appear just yet. If I do a merge wouldn't this branch be pushed to master?

All I want to do is add the files changes that was done in master to my local branch, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, ensure your `master` branch is up-to-date by calling `git checkout master` and doing a pull. Then checkout your branch you wish to pull the changes of `master` into and call `git pull origin master`, that will pull the changes within master, into your branch, essentially bringing your branch up-to-date with master, whilst maintaining any changes you've made.

Answer (score -1):

When you are on the master branch first pull all the changes and update it like this  `git pull -u origin master`. Also, if you have made any changes you can push them too if you want using `git push`
Then checkout to your other branch and there too pull all the changes using `git pull`

This will make your both branches up-to-date.